# (regex,sed) How to append erased word after erasing word

Tags: regex, sed, replace, sh, posix-ere

What I want to change

```
.:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:.:/sbin:/bin
```

What I want to make

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:.
```

I want to pick up all dots ("."), and Want to append to end of the line.
If there is no dot (".") in the line, Then It just print the line.

I can erase dot in the line which have dots. But I can't append dot to end of the line under this condition (`/\.:/`).

```
$ echo /usr/local:.:/bin | sed -r -e "/\.:/s/(\.:)//g"
```

How can I append erased word after I erase word, only with the `sed`command?

Comment: Do you really need to use sed?  Would be much easier in Awk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='.:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:.:/sbin:/bin'
sed -r -e 's/(.+)\.:/.:\1/' -e 's/(.)\.:/\1/g' -e 's/\.:(.+)/\1:./' <<< "$s"
# => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:.
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/lByAzc)

Here,

- `s/(.+)\.:/.:\1/` finds a `.:` substring anywhere in your string and move the `.:` found to the start of the string
- `s/(.)\.:/\1/g` removes all non-initial `.:` char combinations in the string and then
- `s/^\.:(.+)/\1:./` removes the `.:` at the start of the string and pastes `:.` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   
By the way, If there is no dot (".") in the input line, your regex will print dot in the end of line.  
How can I resolve in this case?     

For example, Input line-> `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`  

Should I make one `sed` command in these two case?

Comment: @GRu.L If there are no dots, they are NOT added by my code above, see [the sed demo](https://ideone.com/wwQIvu) with the new string. Share your code if you are not using mine.

Comment: Sorry, You are right. I confused while reading your code.  But In this case(dot exist middle of the line), ->`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:.:/sbin:/bin` Then your code don't print dot in the end of the line.

Comment: @GRu.L Ok, I see, use `sed -r -e 's/(.+)\.:/.:\1/' -e 's/(.)\.:/\1/g' -e 's/\.:(.+)/\1:./'`

Answer (score 0):

You can append another expression to sed: `-e "s/:?$/:./"`.

That means: replace the end of line (and any eventual trailing colon) by a dot.